# Why vector.size() - something can give segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, vector

In following code as expected `for` loop won't run(due to condition `i<0-1`) and nothing will be printed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i < 0-1; i++){
        cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I do the following, vector size is printed 0 as expected. And so `for loop` should not print anything, just like the above case. But in fact something like this is giving me error like segmentation fault or `SIGKILL` after printing `Yes` multiple times(in online ide using C++ 14 gcc 6.3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> a;
    cout<<a.size()<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size()-1;i++){
        cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Other thing I noticed is that it **works as expected** if I replace `a.size() - 1` with just `a.size()`.

Comment: Use the `-Wall` setting to enable warnings and you should see something suspicious.

Comment: The vector's `size()` method returns an unsigned int. So your negative value is converted into something very large.

Comment: `a.size()-1` -- Why not print out the value of `a.size() - 1`, i.e. `std::cout << a.size() -1;`?  That's the issue, so investigate what it is.  Is the value what you expected?

Comment: vector::size return an unsigned number. If you subtract something from unsigned 0 you get a big number instead of -1.

Comment: You could also try your first example except using `for(int i=0; i < 0u-1; i++){` (note the `0u`, an unsigned value).

Comment: I don't want to be *that guy*, but you figured `size - 1` was the issue, why didn't you print `cout << a.size() - 1 << endl;` instead of `cout << a.size() << endl;`? The problem would become apparent. Debugging ability is a highly valued skill.

Comment: This is why you don't ignore compiler warnings

Comment: @SuryanshSingh it happens to the best of us, don't take as critic, but as advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a.size()` returns an unsigned integer. When you subtract 1 from unsigned 0 it underflows (look up "unsigned integer underflow" to 0xFFFFFFFF (a really big number). So your loop runs for a really long time.

In fact since all possible `int`s are less than 0xFFFFFFFF the compiler is smart enough to know that `i<a.size()-1` will *never* be true, and it just turns the loop into an infinite loop.

You can verify this behaviour [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/v946345vv).

The following code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void foo() {
    vector<int> a;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size()-1;i++){
        asm("");
    }
}
```

Is compiled to this assembly:

```
foo():                                # @foo()
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        jmp     .LBB0_1
```

Which is just an infinite loop. The `asm("")` is some magic so that the compiler doesn't remove the loop body.

Answer (score 2):

`1` is an integer literal of type `int`, but `std::vector<int>::size()` returns an unsigned value.

A better comparison would be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i < 0u -1; i++){
        std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`0u` is an unsigned integer literal, and `0u -1` wraps around to a very large number. When you run this code you will see the same effect as with the vectors size.

One workaround is to add rather than subtract:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::cout << a.size() << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i+1 < a.size(); i++){
        std::cout<< "Yes" << std::endl;
    }
}
```